# Excel to Application

Tags: javascript, php, excel, web

I have some excel datasheet with several function in it.
Basically, the function takes 2 vars( 2 cells ) and run my function and return value.

I need to run this excel function inside web app.

give 2 inputs and return values. 
Is there any way to convert this excel file to JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: Why do you want to convert the file? Can't you just write a function in js/php which does the same calculation as the excel formula?

Comment: Do you need to automate the process? If it is a one-time conversion, simply write the function in your favorite programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of an online software called Appizy (http://appizy.com) that does exactly what you ask for but with OpenDocument file: automatically converting the spreadsheet into HTML+Javascript+CSS.

The output is a webapp that acts as your spreasheet.

To use it you have to convert your file into .ods with Libre- or OpenOffice first.

I hope this can help!

Nicolas